# Typescript: NestedKeyOf doesn't work with 3 levels deep nesting

Tags: typescript, nested, typescript-generics, typescript-eslint

I have the following NestedKeyOf type:

```js
type NestedKeyOf<ObjectType extends object> = {
    [Key in keyof ObjectType & (string | number)]: ObjectType[Key] extends object
        ? `${Key}` | `${Key}.${NestedKeyOf<ObjectType[Key]>}`
        : `${Key}`;
}[keyof ObjectType & (string | number)];
```

I have another type that goes as follows:

```js
type DeepObjectA = {
  a: {
    b: {
       c: string
    }
  }
}
```

When trying to create a const of type

```js
const nestedKey = NestedKeyOf<DeepObjectA> = 'a.b.c';
```

I get the following error:

```
Type '"a.b.c"' is not assignable to type 'NestedKeyOf<DeepObjectA>'
```

I want to be able to access any nested key inside any object that I have in my different types.

Comment: Your `NestedKeyOf` type is almost correct but it needs a slight modification to properly handle concatenation of keys for deeply nested objects. The issue arises from the way TypeScript infers and concatenates template literal types. In deeply nested objects, the recursive reference `${Key}.${NestedKeyOf<ObjectType[Key]>}` does not behave as expected due to the distribution over unions that TypeScript performs.

You can solve this issue by introducing an intermediary type that will properly handle the recursion and concatenation of keys: https://pastebin.com/BWNtgDZn